# Windows Server Backup crashing

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, vss

Environment: I'm running an HP DL165 G7, with Windows 2008 R2 x64.

Recently, when I perform a backup with "Windows Server Backup", it will crash the system.  I run the backup over the weekend.  When I come in on Monday, it has the screen shows a BSOD. (I will try to get the info from BSOD).

I have to hold the power button to power down the system.  Then power it back on.  It comes back up normally; all features running: Active Directory, DHCP, DNS, WINS, etc.

I check the event log.  At the start of the backup I get a series of warnings **Event ID 8230**:

> Volume Shadow Copy Service error: Failed resolving account admin6 with status 1376. Check connection to domain controller and VssAccessControl registry key.
>
> Operation:
>     Initializing Writer
>
> Context:
>
> Writer Class Id: {afbab4a2-367d-4d15-a586-71dbb18f8485}
>     Writer Name: Registry Writer
>
> Error-specific details:
>     Error: NetLocalGroupGetMemebers(admin6), 0x80070560, The specified local group does not exist.

Then I get Error **Event ID 8193**

> Volume Shadow Copy Service error: Unexpected error calling routine RegOpenKeyExW(-2147483646,SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\VSS\Diag,...).  hr = 0x80070005, Access is denied.
>   . 
>   Operation:
>     Initializing Writer
>
> Context:
>     Writer Class Id: {e8132975-6f93-4464-a53e-1050253ae220}
>     Writer Name: System Writer
>     Writer Instance ID: {9d7780ba-4e63-4c0e-a90c-c6f492c75870}

I've done some googling.  but most of the responses I've seen involve Small Business System (like this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2537096) or SQL server, which this server does not have.  I'm still searching.

Does the SBS situation apply? I'm thinking no, but need verification.
Anyone experience these errors before? and what solutions were applied?

Comment: 1. I wouldn't suspect the VSS errors to be related to the BSOD. The VSS errors look like permissions problems. 2. If you're going to ask a question about a BSOD then make sure you have the BSOD information to post in the question. There are about a bazillion reasons a Windows machine can BSOD and at this point we'd be guessing as to what's causing yours. 3. I wouldn't think the SBS issue is related to your issue. The SBS issue looks like it's related to the SharePoint VSS writers, which shouldn't exist on your system.

Comment: What joeqwerty said.  BSODs are frequently hardware-related;  perhaps network or hard drive?  That's just a wild guess because we don't have your BSOD info.

Comment: Yeah, I screwed up and didn't get that information.  it was a rush since the company was waiting for the server to come back up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.itexperience.net/2011/09/02/vss-error-failed-resolving-account-administrator-with-status-1376/

this link showed how to do it.  it's  registry change.  go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\VSS\VssAccessControl

Find the account that is shown (in the event log error) and delete that entry.  I guess I misread or didn't understand what this was asking me to do.

I deleted the registry entry and both the errors do not show up during backup.  Hopefully it won't crash the system.  If the BSOD appears again, then it wouldn't be related to this issue and I'll research and start another topic if necessary

Answer (score 1):

The **Event ID 8193** error is caused by installation of the DHCP Server role on your server.  During installation of that role, the registry key referenced in the event log entry (`HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\VSS\Diag`) has its **permissions overwritten, resulting in the `NETWORK SERVICE` account no longer having access to that key**.

This is documented at http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/2298620.

The solution (taken from the MSKB article) is as follows:

1. Download the SubInACL.exe tool from the following Microsoft website: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/confirmation.aspx?familyId=e8ba3e56-d8fe-4a91-93cf-ed6985e3927b&displayLang=en
2. Restore the old permissions together with permissions for the DHCP Server by running the following command:

   ```
   subinacl.exe /Subkeyreg System\CurrentControlSet\Services\VSS\Diag /sddl=O:SYG:SYD:PAI(A;;KA;;;BA)(A;;KA;;;SY)(A;;SDGRGW;;;BO)(A;;SDGRGW;;;LS)(A;;SDGRGW;;;NS)(A;CIIO;RC;;;S-1-3-4)(A;;KR;;;BU)(A;CIIO;GR;;;BU)(A;CIIO;GA;;;BA)(A;CIIO;GA;;;BO)(A;CIIO;GA;;;LS)(A;CIIO;GA;;;NS)(A;CIIO;GA;;;SY)(A;CI;CCDCLCSW;;;S-1-5-80-3273805168-4048181553-3172130058-210131473-390205191)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Open **regedit** and navigate to **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\VSS\VssAccessControl**. Once you done this, delete the account in question by removing the key and restart the computer for changes to take place.